# Django prefetch_related on __str__() method

Tags: django, database, django-rest-framework

My models:

```
class B(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField()

class A(models.Model):
    b = models.OneToOneField(B, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'[{}] Event:'.format(self.b.label)
```

Now, looking queries done during a request with django debug toolbar, i noted that many queries are executed 200+ times. I understand that I will solve using prefetch_related, but where do I have to put it when the lookup is done inside the str method?

Comment: No! Don't put it in `__str__`. Please, post your view code, that's most probably where all those queries are happening

Comment: The 200+ times are caused by selects in form of the browseable API

Comment: well, I don't think that's customizable. And it is OK as long as your end users don't see that page. You should optimize your own views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GenericView` or `ModelViewSet` should have a `queryset` attribute that defines what set it should work on.

You need to add the `prefetch_related` / `select_related` there.

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().prefetch_related('groups')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
```

Comment: is all() necessary?